# How to freeze Y-axis label & make X-axis Scrollable for Angular Ngx-chart Bar Chart

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I would like to produce an Ngx-chart - Stacked Vertical Bar Chart (which is already successful) with a freeze Y-axis when I'm scrolling to the right, whereby the X-axis will continue to scroll, but the Y-axis will stay to indicate me the current value of each bar.

This is almost similar to a behavior of freeze panes of Excel formatting. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share an example or code of what you have tried?

Comment: @skovy as taken from this sample : <https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lj6unq?file=src/app/app.component.ts>